# Difference in Norms

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm taking a multivariable calculus course.

At the moment I'm confused as to the difference between these notations for the norm of a vector (in this case, the vector is in 3 dimensions):

> $|F'(t)|$ where $F(t)$ is a differentiable curve in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

Or

> $\|{F'(t)}\|$ where "..."

Btw, the function is only valid for $t\geq0$ .

Do these both mean to calculate $\sqrt{x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2}$ for $F'(t)$ ?

Comment: Yes, it's the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They mean the same thing. I personally like to stick to the single bars with euclidean vectors of any dimension (continuing to call it magnitude, or length), using the double bars only for vectors more generally.

In particular, in this case (three euclidean space dimensions) I don't see any reason to use $\vert\vert\cdot\vert\vert.$ Always let's be simple.